# Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError - after upgrade gradle plugin version

Tags: android, gradle, assert, crashlytics-android

After upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to `4.1.3` and Gradle wrapper to `6.8.3`, we started getting the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError
```

Failing assertions (**also release**) builds crash the app. I assume the crash is caused by this change:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.1-debug-assertions

Maybe debug builds are OK, but I did not expect this error in **release** builds according to explanation above. Did you ever come across this issue ?

*Before upgrade:* Android Gradle-plugin `3.4.1`, Gradle version `6.2.2`

*After upgrade:* Android Gradle-plugin `4.1.3`, Gradle version `6.8.3`

Regards,

Comment: How is your release build configured in the gradle file?

Comment: Hi @laalto, release build contains obfuscation and signing settings.